# Switching language input using Capslock:how to change by Shift + Caps Lock on LInux?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, language

I have U.S. and Japanese (Hiragana) input on the Windows OS and US array Keyboard. My device is a Chuwi Corebook Pro (Japan) with Windows installed. On this device language switching was done with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>CapsLock</kbd> and I use `CapsLock` toggles to switch between upper and lower case letters.

I would like to switch languages in Linux that way, but <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> then toggles between upper/lower case letters and Language. How do I set it up?

[Reference Video on imgur.com](https://imgur.com/hnPZcdD)

Comment: What distribution of "linux"?, more importantly, what "desktop environment" (DE)? - it is likely here that you will have to change the settings. If it's debian derivative then try a `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-settings`

Comment: DE:Gnome and  Distribution:Kali linux